# What are the different methods to determine if A is diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra

It seems every answer to finding out of a matrix is diagonalizable has a different approach. Where are all these different approaches derived from?

Answer (score 3):

The matrix $A\in\mathcal M_n(\Bbb F)$ is diagonalizable if one of these statement holds

- there's a basis in which the matrix is diagonal
- $\Bbb F^n=\bigoplus_{\lambda\in sp(A)} E_\lambda(A)$
- there's a polynomial with simple roots that annihilates $A$
- the multiplicity of each roots $\lambda$ of the characteristic polynomial is equal to the dimension of $E_\lambda(A)$
- the minimal polynomial has simple roots.

Comment: This is a good list of conditions that are *equivalent* to diagonalizability.  Another commonly used statement is that a matrix is diagonalizable if all of its eigenvalues are distinct (though the converse does not hold).

Comment: Unless you are assuming the field $F$ to be algebraically closed, the phrases "has/with simple roots" should  read: "splits as a product of distinct factors of degree$~1$". The point is that neither "all roots in $F$ are simple" nor "all roots in the algebraic closure $\overline F$ are simple" are the right condition; instead one needs "all roots in the closure $\overline F$ are simple and lie in$~F$".

Comment: I did not find the right sentence; your phrase is the best.@MarcvanLeeuwen